# pushing objects from one array to another

Tags: javascript

i want to push items from one array to another but i'm getting only duplicates of last item. is there a way or better way of working this out? thanks

```js
let nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
let em = [];
let num2 = {id:null, name: ""}

nums.forEach(e => {
  num2.id = e.id;
  num2.name = `${e.first_name} ${e.last_name}`;
  em.push(num2)
});
console.log(em)
```

Comment: This is because each time you're pushing `num2`, its the same object. Clone num2 then push

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you keep pushing the same object to the `em` array in each iteration in the `forEach` loop.

A simple approach would be to do this:

```
const nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
const em = [];

nums.forEach(e => {
  em.push({id: e.id, name: `${e.first_name} ${e.last_name}`});
});

console.log(em);
```

You could also use the `map` functionality on arrays:

```
const nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
const em = nums.map((item) => ({id: item.id, name: `${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`}));
console.log(em);
```

Essentially, we are creating a new object and pushing it into the `em` array in every iteration in the loop and in the process, removing the need for the `num2` object that you've declared.

In addition, the `em` variable can be made `const` since using a `const` variable does not mean that the value it holds is immutable; we're simply pushing new elements into the array [which is perfectly possible](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const).

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the other answers, the issue is that you're changing an existing object every iteration instead of adding a new one.

I'd like to add that that you can also use `reduce` instead (I personally prefer the syntax and it's a bit shorter):

```js
let nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
let em = [];
let num2 = {id:null, name: ""}

em = nums.reduce((accumulator, item) => {
 accumulator.push({
  id: item.id,
  name: `${item.first_name} ${item.last_name}`;
 })
}, [])
```

More info about the `reduce` function can be found in the [MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

---

### Why does it work like this?

If you want to know more about why your solution didn't work, it's important to understand that in JS there's a difference between `primitive values` and `objects`.

By assigning a variable that contains an object to another variable, you are not assigning a new object, but only pointing to an existing one instead. This causes coupling between your objects, they are pointing to the same object, as can be demonstrated here:

```js
var obj1 = {name: 'Sherlock Holmes', country: 'England'}
var obj2 = obj1;

obj2.country = 'US';

console.log(obj1.country) // US
console.log(obj2.country) // US
```

Because of this, when you want to assign an object to another variable you need to clone its content, but create a **new object**, therefor the variable will point to a new object and not to the old one.

There are many ways to do it, but few simple ones are:

1. Using the spread operator like this:

```js
var obj1 = {name: 'Sherlock Holmes', country: 'England'}
var obj2 = { ...obj1 };

obj2.country = 'US';

console.log(obj1.country) // England
console.log(obj2.country) // US
```

2. Stringifying then parsing using `JSON.stringify` and `JSON.parse`

```js
var obj1 = {name: 'Sherlock Holmes', country: 'England'}
var obj2 = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(obj1));

obj2.country = 'US';

console.log(obj1.country) // US
console.log(obj2.country) // US
```

There are more ways, and differences between those ways, if your object has nested objects as well, the replications might not occur correctly, at this point it's best to use a function that does the cloning for you, like lodash's `deepClone` function.

Answer (score 1):

Just clone num2 and push the cloned object.

```js
let nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
let em = [];
let num2 = {id:null, name: ""}

nums.forEach(e => {
  const cloned = {...num2};
  cloned.id = e.id;
  cloned.name = `${e.first_name} ${e.last_name}`;
  em.push(cloned)
});
console.log(em)
```

Answer (score 1):

Your issue is that each time, you're adding the same *object* to the list, `num2`. `num2` itself is not changing through each iteration of the loop.

This is an effect of you never reassigning `num2` to anything new, and the fact that the list `nums` is keeping track of a list of pointers to objects, which means it doesn't actually copy `num2` into itself each time, it just puts `num2`'s pointer in.

You should either 1) clone it or just 2) make a new object then push it to the list.

```js
let nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];
let em = [];
let num2 = {id:null, name: ""}

nums.forEach(e => {
  let temp_num = {...num2};
  temp_num.id = e.id;
  temp_num.name = `${e.first_name} ${e.last_name}`;
  em.push(temp_num)
});
console.log(em)
```

Answer (score 1):

It is a fairly simple `map()` operation to create the new array from the original

```js
let nums = [{id:1, first_name: "sade", last_name: "Smith"}, {id:2, first_name: "Jon", last_name: "Doe"}];

let res = nums.map(({id, first_name:fn, last_name:ln}) => ({id, name: `${fn} ${ln}`}));

console.log(res)
```